# bits to string python

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, bit

I have used this function to convert string to bits.

```
def a2bits(chars):
     return bin(reduce(lambda x, y : (x<<8)+y, (ord(c) for c in chars), 1))[3:]
```

How would I go about doing the reverse? Bits to string. Would I have to separate the bits into ASCII numbers and then convert them into characters?

I got the function *a2bits* from this site: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/221031/string-to-bits

Is there something in the standard library to convert bits to string?

Comment: might take a look at the [Python BitManipulation](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BitManipulation) wiki page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> def bits2a(b):
...     return ''.join(chr(int(''.join(x), 2)) for x in zip(*[iter(b)]*8))
... 
>>> bits2a('0110100001100101011011000110110001101111')
'hello'
```

Comment: You're giving bad example for [new users](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30525854/55075) by not adding any explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
import base64
str(base64.b16decode(hex(int("0110100001100101", base=2))[2:],casefold=True))[2:-1]
```

Comment: Could you also add some explanation?